# TypeError: router .on() is not a function in backbone

Tags: backbone.js

I am a new to `backbone.js` , 
This is my router.js :

```
define([
  'jquery',
  'underscore',
  'backbone'
], function($, _, Backbone ) {

    var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
      routes: {
        '*test': 'defaultAction'
      }
    });


    var initialize = function(){
      var app_router = new AppRouter;

      app_router.on('route:defaultAction', function (test) {
       //alert(2);
      });

      Backbone.history.start();
    };

    return { 
      initialize: initialize
    };
});
```

When I run my index.html, then in my console browser show `TypeError: app_router.on is not a function`.

Can anyone tell me how I can fix it?

Comment: What version of Backbone are you using?

Comment: You're using Backbone version 0.5.3 or earlier, upgrade your Backbone.

Comment: Just now I updated it to Development Version 1.0, then I got `TypeError: Backbone is undefined` in my console :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

maybe you shouldn't call `on` inside of a function, but call it direcly

```
var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
  routes: {
   '*test': 'defaultAction'
   }
});

var app_router = new AppRouter;

app_router.on('route:defaultAction', function (test) {
 //alert(2);
});
```

and delete this

```
return { 
 initialize: initialize
};
```